# Better conflict information on both modified files

Tags: git

Git changes conflicted files (see an example) put minimal information on them and I expect the developer to detect what happened on the conflict. But sometimes, you don't know what change to choose from, and it is necessary to know more, like the specific commit hash/message where the change happened and not only the branch name (like `HEAD` and `distribution` below). Is it possible to configure git to show more verbose output of the conflict?

`3 <<<<<<< HEAD
  4 .icon-cart, .btn.icon-cart {
  5   background-image: url("/plugins/shopping_cart/images/button-icon.png");
  6   background-repeat: no-repeat;
  7   background-position: 5px center;
  8 }

  9 .cart-add-item.small-loading {
 10   background-image: url(/images/loading-small.gif);
 11 }

 12 =======
 13 .icon-cart { 
 14   background: url("/plugins/shopping_cart/images/button-icon.png") no-repeat scroll left center transparent;
 15 }

 16 .cart-add-item.small-loading {
 17   background-image: url(/images/loading-small.gif);
 18 }

 19 >>>>>>> distribution`

Comment: Why not using more informative branch name instead?

Comment: For me it inserts the hash by default (git 1.9.1)

Comment: @Justinas a branch has many commits. A want to see the exact commit where code changed

Comment: @TimCastelijns I'm using git 2.1.1, could you please paste how it appears to you?

Comment: If your developers are hand editing 2-way merge conflicted files to do their merges you have bigger problems.